# Connecting SSAS to Teradata

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, teradata, ssas-2008

I have been building cubes for the last six month and was doing well until I was approached with a new task. This new task was to setup a cube that uses Teradata as it's data source so I get to building the cube and I am able to select a data source and test connection that goes fine. I am able to build a data source view selecting tables from within our teradata infrastructure. I am able to explore the data at the datasource level. So I build the cube and select my measures and build a dimension to go with this cube. so when I go to process this cube I get and Idbconnection error saying that the teradata client has thrown an exception. Keep in mind I am able to right click on the tables in the data source view and explore the data. If anyone has any insight on what I may be doing wrong and if any other information is needed let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution that I came up with was to make the server that houses teradata a linked server. In doing so I was able to query the data I needed to build and process the cube. I am thinking just talking of the top of my head but I think analysis services prefers to use linked servers so that it looks like you are pulling from a microsoft object. This would be perceived to considering microsofts proprietary development tactics. Who knows it works now and I am happy.